# Error java.lang.NullPointerException on a executable

Tags: java

I have created a java application to connect to a MySQL database. 
Once through the program install creator I created an .exe .

This executable runs, and the first form is login. When he tries to access the database to confirm the details of login gives this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Someone can help me solve this? The path is correct, because if run the .jar the application runs normally.

I apologize for the inconvenience.

[image]

Only have this to try explain better my question :S

I'm so sorry... I'm running a executable version from my java aplication.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sensores.forms.jTMainMenu.initComponents(jTMainMenu.java:786)
    at sensores.forms.jTMainMenu.<init>(jTMainMenu.java:57)
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta.jBLoginActionPerformed(jTLoginConsulta.java:351)
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta.access$000(jTLoginConsulta.java:59)
    at sensores.forms.jTLoginConsulta$1.actionPerformed(jTLoginConsulta.java:110)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Stacktrace *and* code ?

Comment: No, we unfortunately cannot help without more context (like the previous comment, for example).

Comment: Clearly you're trying to dereference an object which is set to `null`.  I'm afraid we can't be any more specific without seeing any code or debugging information.

Comment: You can try to launch the exe from the command line and see what ia output.

Comment: Thanks everyone to reply.How is running the executable version, the specific error does not appear.

Comment: Joop Eggen how can I do that?

Comment: I edit my question with Stacktrace.

Comment: Can you decompress your generated .exe file with a tool like 7zip? Perhaps the resources in the jar file were not inserted in the .exe file , namely images, properties files, etc...

Comment: Look at these two lines of code, do you have anything that would not have initialized if you are running your code thru exe.
Can you paste these lines of code and show us that all objects used on these lines are properly initialized.
    jTMainMenu.java - line 786
    jTMainMenu.java - line 57

You have an object which has null reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in this class/line

```
jTMainMenu.java:786
```

Seems you tried to load a image in this point of your code, i don't know how you are generating a executable from your java code but this may be the source of the problem. Try to put this image outside of your executable/jar and use a relative path to load the image, like './my_image'.

You also have to take care if your user make a link to your executable, in this case a relative path can't resolve your problem. A simple way to solve this in java is get the source code location.

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

And use this location to find your image.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the line number from the Stacktrace where you are getting the NullPointerException.
it is straight forward to find out the null pointer exception. Object is null or not initialize on which you are calling the method

```
try{

   // add database connection statement here

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printstacktrace();
}
```

// run the program from the command prompt.

// you can print the e.printstacktrace() on the popup as well to get the exception details

Comment: Very thanks for reply. I edit my question with Stacktrace. It helps to undertand my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you make a .jar, move that jar somewhere separate from the IDE (i.e. their classpaths), and start the jar, do you receive a NullPointerException?

This can be caused by **resources**, getResource, getResourceAsStreem, getBundle, as they are not **case-sensitive** in the Windows file system, but are case sensitive in a jar(and under Linux/MacOS).

(Also **File** cannot be used for jar resources.)

You might look in the jar with 7zip or so to inspect all paths.

Comment: If Imake a .jar, move that jar somewhere separate from the IDE (i.e. their classpaths), and start the jar, I receive another error diferent that  NullPointerException...

Comment: Disappointing, but getting a jar to work in isolation would be a first milestone. If ClassNotFoundException, one needs library jars on the class path, or better in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Class-Path entry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not getting image icon in defined path

```
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following two guesses:

- There is a problem with your path or classpath and loading the resource
- The lines

  at sensores.forms.jTMainMenu.initComponents(jTMainMenu.java:786)
  at sensores.forms.jTMainMenu.(jTMainMenu.java:57)

  indicate that something is initialized. Usually Swing/AWT uses multiple threads, so you might have a race condition here: The reference to the resource is handed to `ImageIcon` in your `ìnitComponents` method before another thread could set the value to something non-null. Try using proper synchronization/locking.